# Nissan keeps losing Bluetooth connectivity to my phone

Tags: bluetooth-audio, google-pixel

I originally posted a version of this question to mechanics.stackexchange, under the assumption that something was wrong w/ my 2013 Nissan Altima SV.  However, it sounds like it's an issue that only affects Android phones, not iPhones or Windows phones.

*My car offers Bluetooth connectivity, and that feature worked great for about a year; for phonecalls, podcasts, and music.*

*However, for some time now, when I start my car and navigate to AUX to listen to my phone, it occasionally says, "No devices connected". When I navigate through the menus to look at Bluetooth devices, the car still has my phone listed in its devices, it's just unable to connect.*

*When this happens, I have to delete my phone from the list of devices, and re-add it. Then, it will work fine for another week or two, before the same problem occurs.*

I have a Google Pixel (first generation).  Is this a known issue with Android Bluetooth functionality?

Comment: It isn't normal. Try disconnecting the battery leads so that the power to the unit is disabled for about 10 minutes. That should  clear the cache of the unit and *may* help

Comment: The car battery leads?  That would imply that it's not an Android issue, but a car issue?

Comment: Neither. It is to reset the device in car and purge it clean . Can't say it will solve but may help. Likewise, on your device clear the Bluetooth app cache and data. It's like starting afresh from both ends of Bluetooth